# SharePoint Migration 2013 enterprise

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, migration

We are migrating Sharepoint 2010 farm to SharePoint 2013. Is it better to use same Farm Admin account for new SharePoint 2013 farm ?

Answer (score 3):

I would go with the new service account, i am sure it is not best practice to share the account between the farms.

- Managing the password of the farm admin account with two farms is big issue.
- if you locked out the account, both farm will go down.

But if you are going to decommission the sharepoint 2010 farm as soon as migration completed then i may do this.

But again, as best practice use the new farm admin account.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sarwar.... One more query.. we need to install SharePoint 2013 using farm admin account right?

Comment: i prefer seprate service account to install it i.e called installation account. farm admin will run all the services but install account resposnible to install every thing ie installation of sharepoint, service pack, patches, powershell etc